# Question about notation in a simple circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, notation

I was given this circuit in an Electricity & Magnetism course.

[image]

On the far left, is that a current source providing 2A? It seems to be but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Yes, that's an ideal current source.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: It's a current source. The direction of the arrow indicates the direction of the current. Note that if it was an ideal galvanometer, it would short out the 40 Ohm resistor.

Comment: Studying Kirchov's law?

Comment: Your diagram can't be totally correct.  The 2A current flow through the 10 ohm resistor will produce a voltage drop of 20V, which is more than the 12V battery in your diagram.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [electronics.se].